# Distributed Tornado-Based Chat Server

Tags: comet, distributed, tornado, long-polling

I have a requirement to build a distributed Comet-based server for a large number of clients (over 500K concurrent) with high throughput. I'm currently investigating the possibility of using Tornado for it's high efficiency in dealing with high number of long-polling requests.

My concern is whether a single Tornado server could handle such a large number of long polling clients. As an experiment, I would like to expand Tornado Chat demo (https://github.com/facebook/tornado/tree/master/demos/chat) to a distributed environment. I.e. have a bunch of Tornado chat servers running in parallel, each responsible for a changing set of clients.

I would appreciate any ideas/thoughts you have with regard to implementing such a scheme, or any references to relevant resources.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general to make the basic chat distributed across several Tornado instances you need to create a distributed message passing mechanism, the most straightforward implementation will be to just use some kind of message queue like RabbitMQ (or it's competitor) and send fanout messages when user types something, while all connections are listening.

Comment: Ivan, how rabbitmq will be useful in this case?

Comment: RabbitMQ helps to deliver message from client served by one tornado instance, chat.services.com:8001, to another client served by another tornado instance, chat.services.com:8002. The main challenge is to keep the state of each online user (presence): whether it online, offline, idle. Facebook, for example, developed idle strategy algorithm: that determines user activity as idle for 1, 2, 5, 8, 11 seconds ... and so on. It helps to significantly decrease network load and reach nice throughput.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought about this is to have an Nginx server/reverse proxy in the front-end, while have multiple instances of Tornado in the back, this could be a Tornado instance per process, try to do some bench-marking to your machine to see how many running Tornado instances on different process a machine can handle, when you notice degradation in performance, start doing the same thing on another machine.

Nginx will round robin all the servers you have to distribute the load over the long-polling/Tornado servers/instances.

Not really sure how the rabbitmq will be useful in this case.